# Android not detecting beacon from background

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon, beacon

I am working on beacon using [Altbeacon](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html) library. I am trying to detect beacon in the background as mentioned [here](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/background_launching.html). My apps activity monitors the beacon and returns values properly. But when I kill the app, the app is not detecting beacon. The following is my Application class.

```
public class BeaconApplication extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier{

private static final String TAG = "BeaconApplication";
private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
private boolean haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = false;
private MainActivity mainActivity = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    BeaconManager beaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(5000l); // 5 secs
    beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(5000l); // 5 secs
    Log.d(TAG, "setting up background monitoring for beacons and power saving");
    Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion",
            Identifier.parse("fda50693-a4e2-4fb1-afcf-c6eb07647825"), Identifier.parse("10004"), Identifier.parse("54480"));
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);

}

@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    Log.d(TAG, "did enter region. UniqueId: "+ region.getId1());
    if (!haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "auto launching MainActivity");
        sendNotification();

        haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = true;
    } else {
        if (mainActivity != null) {
            mainActivity.logToDisplay("I see a beacon again" );
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Sending notification.");
            sendNotification();
        }


 }

}



@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    if (mainActivity != null) {
        mainActivity.logToDisplay("I no longer see a beacon.");
    }
}

@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {
    if (mainActivity != null) {
        mainActivity.logToDisplay("I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: " + i);
    }
}

private void sendNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Welcome to beacon zone")
                    .setContentText("You are in a beacon zone.")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    builder.setSound(alarmSound);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}

public void setMonitoringActivity(MainActivity activity) {
    this.mainActivity = activity;
}
}
```

And here is my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:name=".BeaconApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: I don't know why this question got minus. What is wrong with this question?

Comment: When you say "kill", do you mean swipe it off the screen from the recent task list or a force stop from application settings?  What device model and OS version is this?

Comment: Hey @davidgyoung, I mean swiping it off the screen from the recent task list. I use Samsung galaxy note II - GT-N7100.

Answer (score 0):

Some users have reported that **certain Samsung devices prohibit app functionality one you kill the app from the task switcher until it is manually relaunched**.  The standard Android behavior is that killing an app from the task switcher allows automated relaunch, but killing an app with a force stop in settings does not allow automated relaunch.  It seems that in some Samsung builds, swiping off with the task switcher does a non-standard force stop, rather than a regular stop operation as prescribed by Android.

There is a [tracking issue](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/44) about this in the Android Beacon Library.  In contains a link to a [special test app](https://github.com/davidgyoung/power-connect-tester) you can build and use to characterize how this functionality works on your device.  Following the instructions in this issue and reporting the results would be very helpful in figuring out what is going on.  For better or worse, the fragmented nature of Android means that every device behaves slightly differently and must be characterized separately.

In addition to running the above, it would be helpful to know the operating system version and build number on the specific device that has this problem.